# Showing Undefined for the name in collection of data base

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, mongoose

`I was trying to read only names of fruit but it is showing me undefined

// getting-started.js const mongoose = require('mongoose');`your text` const { Schema } = mongoose; `your text` main().catch(err =\> console.log(err)); async function main() { await mongoose. Connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/Fruitsdb'); console.log('Database connected'); } const fruitSchema = new mongoose.Schema({ name: { type: String, required: true }, rating: { type: Number, min: \[1, "Please give rating"\], max: \[5, "Enter valid rating"\] }, review: String }); const Fruit = mongoose.model("Fruit", fruitSchema); const Apple = new Fruit({ name: 'Apple', rating: 5, review: "Very good fruit" }); // Apple.save() const kiwi = new Fruit({ name: "Kiwi", rating: 10,`your text` review: "The Best Fruit!" }); const orange = new Fruit({ name: "Orange", rating: 6, review: "The Sour Fruit!" }); const banana = new Fruit({ name: "Banana", rating: 8, review: "The Digestive Fruit!" }); // Fruit.insertMany(\[kiwi, orange, banana\]) // try { // console.log("Successfully saved all the fruits to fruitsDB"); // } catch (error) { // console.log(error); // } const Mango = new Fruit({ name: "Mango", rating: 4, review: "King of Fruits" }); // Mango.save(); Fruit.find() .then(function (fruits) { fruits.forEach(function (fruit) { console.log(fruits.name); }) }) .catch(function (err) { console.log(err); });`

Comment: Please edit your question so it is more understandable. https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help may help.

Answer (score 1):

Inside the `forEach` loop, when you are trying to log the name of each fruit, you should use `fruit.name` instead of `fruits.name`. The variable `fruit` represents an individual item from the `fruits` array, so you should access its properties using `fruit.propertyName`.

Here's the corrected code:

```
Fruit.find().then(function (fruits) {
fruits.forEach(function (fruit) {
    console.log(fruit.name);
})
}).catch(function (err) {
    console.log(err);
});
```